# Java 11: Criteria API and extra select fields

Tags: java, criteria-api

I have a query expressed via Criteria API, however I see that this query selects extra
fields that which I did not ask. I've read that I can make some fields inside entities to load
lazily, however I do not want to change a current situation about fetch. Is there any way, using Criteria API, to select ONLY the fields that I need without touching fetch mode?

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: thank you for your response. It is a general question 

Do I need to make some fields in some entities lazy loaded for Criteria API to generate
a query with only selected values?